# Transfer Variable from TableViewController to TableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

In the current project I'm working on I need to transfer variables from view to view.
I successfully transferred a variable from a tableviewcontroller to a UIviewcontroller like this.

```
if segue.identifier == "Done" {
            let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let transfer = nav.topViewController as! quizViewController
            transfer.questionArrays = questions2
        }
```

But when I tried to transfer a variable from a tableviewcontroller to a tableview controller like this,

```
if segue.identifier == "answerSegue" {
            let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let transfer = nav.topViewController as! answersTableViewController
            transfer.index = rowIndex
        }
```

I get an error saying

"Could not cast value of type list2.answersTableViewController"

So the question is, how can I transfer a variable from a UITableViewController to a UITableViewController?

Here is my story board.
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLEeX.jpg)

Comment: Can you try to tell us in a clear schematic way your view hierarchy?

Comment: are you sure the destination controller of the "answerSegue" is a navigation controller (whose root controller is `answersTableViewController`?

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, the second `UINavigationController` isn't needed. If you don't have any reason to use an extra navigation controller I'd suggest you remove it and use one of the solution provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cast:

```
let transfer = nav.topViewController as! quizViewController
```

Then you cast:

```
let transfer = nav.topViewController as! answersTableViewController
```

This code is actually a bit strange and it's not possible to find out without posting more details.

Normally, you don't access the target controller over UINavigationController. You simply do something like:

```
let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! YourDestinationControllerClass
destinationController.variable = value
```

No need to involve UINavigationController at all.

Maybe this would work in your case ? :

```
if segue.identifier == "answerSegue" {
  let transfer  = segue.destinationViewController as! answersTableViewController
  transfer.index = rowIndex  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your storyboard the second UITableViewController doesn't have its own UINavigationController. Try this instead:

```
if segue.identifier == "answerSegue" {
    let transfer = segue.destinationViewController as! answersTableViewController
    transfer.index = rowIndex
}
```